# Checkboxes refine search from mysql table stored with comma seperated fields

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I am implementing a refine search for mysql query based on checked check boxes value and matching value stored in Mysql database table. Check box fields are as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="services_search[]" id="services_search[]" /> Service ABC

<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="services_search[]" id="services_search[]" /> Service XYZ

<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="services_search[]" id="services_search[]" /> Service 123
```

I have a mysql table "users" with fields id, name and services. Field "services" have one or more service value stored something like this:

```
|  id  |  name   |  services 
|  1   |  Mark   | 1, 2, 3
|  2   |  Jhon   | 2, 3
|  3   |  Tina   | 1
```

Now my question is how to implement mysql query to get refined result based on multiple checked services.

Comment: I think you should alter your database schema for starters. If multiple services can belong to a user, possible services should be in a separate table with a table that connects the two in between.

Answer (score 0):

Because **one user can have many services** and **one service can belong to multiple users**, a better course of action would be a ***many-to-many*** relationship table.

Your example would be structured as such:

#### Users table

```
id | name
---+-----
1  | Mark
2  | John
3  | Tina
```

#### Services Table

```
id | service
---+--------
1  | Normal
2  | Premium
3  | Admin
```

#### Tables to Users

```
user_id | service_id
--------+-----------
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
2       | 1
2       | 2
3       | 1
```

Where user_id and service_id have foreign keys to the respective fields in the main tables. Now it's easily maintainable, does not require string manipulation, and easily queryable.